# Number of Inversion Count in an array. Using Merge Sort

Tags: c++, algorithm, mergesort

For those how not know about inversion.

Inversion-

Given an array A of N integers, an inversion of the array is defined as any pair of indexes (i,j) such that i < j and A[i] > A[j].

Inshort:

**{inv}(A) =    {(A(i),A(j)),  i < j { and } A(i) > A(j)}**

For example, the array a={2,3,1,5,4} has three inversions: (1,3), (2,3), (4,5), for the pairs of entries (2,1), (3,1), (5,4).

Total inversion count = 3.

Well, I tried to solve this question by utilizing the standard merge sort.
Here is how I think it works.

Assume that at some stage, partA and partb of your merge sort is

partA- [1,2,3].

partB- [4,5]

Now, Let X be the element of the first array, partA. Y be for second array, partB.

If X is copied to output array(i.e if X < Y) - Then we have no Inversion.

Else If Y is copied to output array(i.e if X > Y). 
Then we have Inversion count = count + mid - i+1. (i being the position of that element). As it is sorted in increasing order, all the elements at position j > i, X[j] > Y.

Here's the code further details.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
using namespace std;

vector<int> a;
vector<int> c;
void merge(int low, int high, int mid);
void mergesort(int low, int high)
{
 int mid;
 if (low < high)
 {
     mid=(low+high)/2;
     mergesort(low,mid);
     mergesort(mid+1,high);
     merge(low,high,mid);
 }
return ;
}

int count ; //to store the inversion count
void merge(int low, int high, int mid)
{
int i, j, k;
i = low;
k = low;
j = mid + 1;
// standard merging from merge sort
while (i <= mid && j <= high)
{
    if (a[i] < a[j])
    {
        c[k] = a[i];
        k++;
        i++;
    }
    else
    {
        c[k] = a[j];
        k++;
         j++;
      //   cout<<a[i]<<" "<<mid<<" "<<i<<"\n";
         count += mid - i+1; // This is where the trick occurs, if X > Y,
         //eg. in [3, 4, 5] and [1,2]
         //if(3>1) then 4,5 is obviously greater then 1, thus making count as mid - i+1              
     }
 }
while (i <= mid)
{
    c[k] = a[i];
    k++;
    i++;
}
while (j <= high)
{
    c[k] = a[j];
    k++;
    j++;
}
for (i = low; i < k; i++)
{
    a[i] = c[i];
 }
}
int main()
{
//int a[20], i, b[20];
int T;
cin>>T;
while(T--){
    //cout<<"enter  the elements\n";
    int N;
    cin>>N;
    count =0;
    a.clear(); a.resize(N);
    c.clear(); c.resize(N);
    for (int i = 0; i < N; i++)
    {
        cin>>a[i];
    }
    mergesort(0, N-1);

    cout<<count<<"\n";
}
}
```

OK, Now coming to my doubt, I believe that the above implemented logic is legit enough to solve the number of inversions, but for some strange reason its not, I'm not sure whats causing WA here.

I'm stuck at this for some time, not able to figure it out.
It's not a homework Question, its just that I see no wrong with the logic and the code still doesn't work, what may be the possible reason? Help!.

Ideone Link - https://ideone.com/nmvl7i

Question on Spoj - http://www.spoj.com/problems/INVCNT/

Note: The first two test cases are working fine, While submitting I'm getting WA.

Comment: your description of an inversion is lacking, I had to checkout the Wikipedia page for clarification. http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inversion_%28discrete_mathematics%29
Perhaps saying, a pair of indices (i, j) where i < j and A[i] > A[j]

Comment: Thanks for pointing that out, I've updated it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem for your solution is the result may be larger than the integer range, for example, if the sequence are n, n - 1, ... , 1, (non increasing) the number of inversion will be n*(n - 1)/2 and with n = 2*10^5, the result will be much larger than integer range.

So, change `int count` into `long long count` and

Change this line:

```
count += mid - i + 1;
```

into:

```
count += (long long)mid - (long long) i + 1L;
```

You will get accepted answer.

My [accepted code](http://ideone.com/16kEoV)

Comment: Yup, you are right, I figured it out, and got accepted, Just lazy to not post it here. Anyway thanks for elaborating it, might be useful for others. One more thing, I think for non-increasing sequence, the answer should be N*(N-1)/2, rather than N*(N+1)/2. Example if array is [5, 4, 3, 2, 1]. Then the inversions are [{5,4}, {5,3}, {5,2}, {5,1}] - Total =4. [{4,3}, {4,2}, {4,1}] . Total += 3 . [{3,2}, {3,1}]. Total+= 2. [{2,1}]. Total+= 1.   4+3+2+1 = 10 which is equal to, 5*(5-1)/2 = 5*4/2 =5*2 =10.

Comment: @user3232918 thanks, you are right about that. And can you accept this answer also if it answered your question :) ?